# SIFT using Python 3.4

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.4 with naconda 2.3.0 to try the SIFT in MacOS, but there is always command not found when executing my code. Vlfeat 0.9.20 sift and the lib files are included but no idea what's wrong. My code is as below:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import os

def process_image(imagename, resultname, params="--edge-thresh 10 --peak-thresh 5"):
    """  Process an image and save the results in a file."""

    if imagename[-3:] != 'pgm':
        # create a pgm file
        im = Image.open(imagename).convert('L')
        im.save('tmp.pgm')
        imagename = 'tmp.pgm'

    cmmd = str("sift" + imagename + "--output=" + resultname+ "" +params)
    os.system(cmmd)
    print ('processed', imagename, 'to', resultname)
```

and the error from the compiler is:

```
sh: sifttmp.pgm--output=IMG0232.sift--edge-thresh: command not found
```

it cannot transfer to feature file and breaks down

I have consulted from the internet and tried some modifications but it still does not work. Is there any other transformation from Python2.X to 3.X? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The SIFT comand line tool is as far as I can see called `sift`. But due to faulty string operations, the final command does not include the required spaces, and is thus instead `sifttmp.pgm--output=IMG0232.sift--edge-thresh`, which obviously does not exist.

Replace

```
cmmd = str("sift" + imagename + "--output=" + resultname+ "" +params)
```

with

```
 cmmd = "sift {} --output={} {}".format(imagename, resultname, params)
```

The above is cleaner to read, and will contain the spaces missing in your current code.
It might be that the `sift` executable is not on the path, and then you might have to give it the full (absolute) path. E.g. if you have `sift` in the directory `/User/foo/Applications/`:

```
 cmmd = "/User/foo/Applications/sift {} --output={} {}".format(imagename, resultname, params)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified the code but it still does not work and the error is the same. I double-checked the Libvl and sift are in the same folder with my sift.py file. It seems like that Python cannot catch the sift to transfer data. Maybe the problem is using cmmd in Python 3.4, will it ?

Comment: If you did the change I suggested, you can not possibly have gotten exactly the same error message. It might be that it still can't find the `sift` executable. In that case, add the full path to it. I will update my answer to show that.

Comment: Thanks, it succeed. Although I can get the sift result, the way to put the path in the programming code is not executable. I will keep going on to find a better solution.